# c# - SQLITE and dataGridView1

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

i search and i search buy i cant find a solution
this is my code

```
private void pointage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM company";
            command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connectiondb);
            DataSet1 mydata = new DataSet1();
            SQLiteDataAdapter zz = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, connectiondb);
            zz.Fill(mydata.Tables["DataTable1"]);

            int i;
            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[1].Clone();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                    for (i = 0; i <= System.Convert.ToUInt32(reader["id"]); i++)
                    {
                        row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i];
                        row.Cells["Column10"].Value = reader["firstname"].ToString();
                        row.Cells["Column9"].Value = reader["lastname"].ToString();
                    }
            }

        }
```

what i need do, if i leave this lines

```
                     row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i];
                     row.Cells["Column10"].Value = reader["firstname"].ToString();
                     row.Cells["Column9"].Value = reader["lastname"].ToString();
```

and i put just

```
MessageBox.Show(reader["firstname"].ToString());
```

that will work but when i do that

```
 for (i = 0; i <= System.Convert.ToUInt32(reader["id"]); i++)
                         {
                             row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i];
                             row.Cells["Column10"].Value = reader["firstname"].ToString();
                             row.Cells["Column9"].Value = reader["lastname"].ToString();
                         }
```

that not work :'(

what ill do, help me please

Comment: Can you elaborate on "that not work"? Do you get an exception? And what are you trying to accomplish with that `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

ok guys finaly i find the solution :D

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        i = System.Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"].ToString());
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

        MessageBox.Show(System.Convert.ToString(i));
        DataGridViewRow R = dataGridView1.Rows[i-1];

        R.Cells["Column9"].Value = reader["firstname"].ToString();
        R.Cells["Column10"].Value = reader["lastname"].ToString();

    }
```